# Convert INT data type into DateTime Format

Tags: sql

**//This is my script**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN iPaid_dt>= 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8),iPaid_dt)) ELSE '' END AS [TRANSACTION DATE]
FROM MyTable
```

**//My OutPut is**

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000  
2012-11-11 00:00:00.000  
2012-10-26 00:00:00.000
```

**//Expected Output:**

```
2012-11-11 00:00:00.000  
2012-10-26 00:00:00.000
```

//The `1900-01-01` output should be '' only, What is the correct script? note: `iPaid_dt` is `INT` with 0 as default value.

Comment: put ELSE NULL instead Else ''

Comment: And what *is* the value of that `iPaid_nt` for that 1900 date?

Comment: use ISNULL function and change value to desire value :  isnull(x,'')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing field types and SQL Server is converting `''` to a `DATETIME` for you. Try this:

```
SELECT    CASE
              WHEN iPaid_dt > 0
                  THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23),
                        CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8),iPaid_dt)))
              ELSE ''
          END AS [TRANSACTION DATE]
FROM      MyTable
```

Answer (score 3):

A `CASE` expression must have a single data type that all possible values for all rows must belong to. Since `DATETIME` has a higher precedence than `VARCHAR`, all of the possible values are being forced to be `DATETIME`s. So the `''` is converted back to a `DATETIME`.

I can't say how to fix it since I don't know why you're doing this conversion in the first place. Maybe `NULL` would be a better placeholder than `''`?